# How to calculate element wise minimum/maximum between two same size numpy matrices in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried this way:

```
A = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(4,1))
B = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(4,1))
C = np.min(A, B)
```

Let's A and B be as given below:

```
A = [[0.13456968]
     [0.80465702]
     [0.08426155]
     [0.85041178]]

B = [[0.64932459]
     [0.77806739]
     [0.15517366]
     [0.10992883]]
```

I want to have C as given below:

```
C = [[0.13456968]
     [0.77806739]
     [0.08426155]
     [0.10992883]]
```

But this gives following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Use np.minimum() and np.maximum(). See [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) for more details. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use minimum() instead of min():

```
A = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(4,1))
B = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(4,1))
C = np.minimum(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with

```
C = np.minimum.reduce([A, B])
```